# Grouping *almost* unique ids

Tags: xslt

I'm struggling with grouping ids that are almost the same.  Basically I need to group the content of the PF.A1PF and PersIntr.Personnel.AlPersonnelActive sections and strip the substring before to get my id. I do not have a listing of all the section ids.

Please see below for examples.

Here's the current XML:

```
<group>
<section id="unique_1_Connect_42_PF.AlPF">
    <msgph id="doc" xml:lang="en_US">It has been a external net failure. The pumps are
        blocked.</msgph>
    <msgph id="cstext" xml:lang="en_US">Mains error</msgph>
    <msgph id="localtext" xml:lang="en_US">Mains error</msgph>
</section>
<section id="unique_1_Connect_42_PersIntr.Personnel.AlPersonnelActive">
    <msgph id="doc" xml:lang="en_US">Personal alarm warning time has run out without reset.
        Personnel in danger !</msgph>
    <msgph id="cstext" xml:lang="en_US">Personal alarm</msgph>
    <msgph id="localtext" xml:lang="en_US">Pers. alarm</msgph>
</section>
<section id="unique_2_Connect_42_PF.AlPF">
    <msgph id="doc" xml:lang="es_ES">Ha habido un fallo de red externa. Las bombas están
        bloquedas.</msgph>
    <msgph id="cstext" xml:lang="es_ES">Fallo energía de entrada</msgph>
    <msgph id="localtext" xml:lang="es_ES">Fallo energía</msgph>
</section>
<section id="unique_2_Connect_42_PersIntr.Personnel.AlPersonnelActive">
    <msgph id="doc" xml:lang="es_ES">Tiempo de espera de la alarma de personal ha finalizado sin
        reseteo. ¡Personal en peligro!</msgph>
    <msgph id="cstext" xml:lang="es_ES">Alarma personal</msgph>
    <msgph id="localtext" xml:lang="es_ES">Alarma personal</msgph>
</section>
```

Here's what I need to output:

```
<Rsc Id="PF.AlPF">
    <Documentation en_US="It has been a external net failure. The pumps are blocked."
        es_ES="Ha habido un fallo de red externa. Las bombas están bloquedas."/>
    <CSText en_US="Mains error" es_ES="Fallo energía de entrada"/>
    <LocalText en_US="Mains error" es_ES="Fallo energía"/>
</Rsc>
<Rsc Id="PersIntr.Personnel.AlPersonnelActive">
    <Documentation
        en_US="Personal alarm warning time has run out without reset. Personnel in danger !"
        es_ES="Tiempo de espera de la alarma de personal ha finalizado sin reseteo. ¡Personal en peligro!"/>
    <CSText en_US="Personal alarm" es_ES="Alarma personal"/>
    <LocalText en_US="Pers. alarm" es_ES="Alarma personal"/>
</Rsc>
```

I really appreciate any insight. Thanks in advance for your attention.

Kind regards,
Anne

---

**Update**:
Thanks so much, @Dimitre, @Michael. I really appreciate your help with this challenge. I had a little trouble with the element resolving in this portion of the 2.0 solution:

```
<xsl:element name="{$vNewNames[starts-with(lower-case(.),current()/@id)]}">
    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
        <xsl:attribute name="{@xml:lang}" select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:element>
```

**Here's what finally worked:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/*">
    <Resources>
        <Type key="Alarm">
            <xsl:for-each-group select="//section" group-by="substring-after(@id, '_42_')">
                <xsl:variable name="currentID" select="substring-after(@id, '_42_')"/>
                <xsl:element name="Rsc">
                    <xsl:attribute name="id" select="$currentID"/>                        
                    <xsl:for-each-group select="//section[$currentID]/msgph"
                        group-by="substring-after(@id, '_42_')">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="substring-after(@id, '_42_')='doc'">
                                <Documentation>
                                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                                        <xsl:if test="contains(parent::*/@id,$currentID)">
                                            <xsl:attribute name="{@xml:lang}" select="."/>
                                        </xsl:if>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </Documentation>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:when test="substring-after(@id, '_42_')='cstext'">
                                <CSText>
                                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                                        <xsl:if test="contains(parent::*/@id,$currentID)">
                                            <xsl:attribute name="{@xml:lang}" select="."/>
                                        </xsl:if>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </CSText>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:when test="substring-after(@id, '_42_')='localtext'">
                                <LocalText>
                                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                                        <xsl:if test="contains(parent::*/@id,$currentID)">
                                            <xsl:attribute name="{@xml:lang}" select="."/>
                                        </xsl:if>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </LocalText>
                            </xsl:when>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </xsl:for-each-group>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </Type>
    </Resources>
</xsl:template>
```

Thanks again!
Anne

Comment: Is the prefix' pattern fixed like `unique_#_Connect_42_`?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete solution that uses the Muenchian method for grouping.

Answer (score 1):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:key name="ksectById" match="section"
  use="substring-after(@id, '42_')"/>

 <xsl:template match=
 "section[generate-id()
         =
          generate-id(key('ksectById',
                      substring-after(@id, '42_')
                         )[1]
                      )
         ]
 ">
  <xsl:variable name="vId" select=
  "substring-after(@id, '42_')"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vGroup" select=
   "key('ksectById',$vId)"/>

  <Rsc Id="{$vId}">
   <Documentation>
     <xsl:apply-templates select=
      "$vGroup/msgph[@id='doc']/@xml:lang"/>
   </Documentation>
   <CSText>
     <xsl:apply-templates select=
      "$vGroup/msgph[@id='cstext']/@xml:lang"/>
   </CSText>
   <LocalText>
     <xsl:apply-templates select=
      "$vGroup/msgph[@id='localtext']/@xml:lang"/>
   </LocalText>
  </Rsc>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="@xml:lang">
  <xsl:attribute name="{.}">
   <xsl:value-of select=".."/>
  </xsl:attribute>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*/*" priority="-1"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<group>
    <section id="unique_1_Connect_42_PF.AlPF">
        <msgph id="doc" xml:lang="en_US">It has been a external net failure. The pumps are blocked.</msgph>
        <msgph id="cstext" xml:lang="en_US">Mains error</msgph>
        <msgph id="localtext" xml:lang="en_US">Mains error</msgph>
    </section>
    <section id="unique_1_Connect_42_PersIntr.Personnel.AlPersonnelActive">
        <msgph id="doc" xml:lang="en_US">Personal alarm warning time has run out without reset. Personnel in danger !</msgph>
        <msgph id="cstext" xml:lang="en_US">Personal alarm</msgph>
        <msgph id="localtext" xml:lang="en_US">Pers. alarm</msgph>
    </section>
    <section id="unique_2_Connect_42_PF.AlPF">
        <msgph id="doc" xml:lang="es_ES">Ha habido un fallo de red externa. Las bombas están bloquedas.</msgph>
        <msgph id="cstext" xml:lang="es_ES">Fallo energía de entrada</msgph>
        <msgph id="localtext" xml:lang="es_ES">Fallo energía</msgph>
    </section>
    <section id="unique_2_Connect_42_PersIntr.Personnel.AlPersonnelActive">
        <msgph id="doc" xml:lang="es_ES">Tiempo de espera de la alarma de personal ha finalizado sin reseteo. ¡Personal en peligro!</msgph>
        <msgph id="cstext" xml:lang="es_ES">Alarma personal</msgph>
        <msgph id="localtext" xml:lang="es_ES">Alarma personal</msgph>
    </section>
</group>
```

**produces exactly the wanted, correct result**:

```
<Rsc Id="PF.AlPF">
   <Documentation en_US="It has been a external net failure. The pumps are blocked." es_ES="Ha habido un fallo de red externa. Las bombas están bloquedas."/>
   <CSText en_US="Mains error" es_ES="Fallo energía de entrada"/>
   <LocalText en_US="Mains error" es_ES="Fallo energía"/>
</Rsc>
<Rsc Id="PersIntr.Personnel.AlPersonnelActive">
   <Documentation en_US="Personal alarm warning time has run out without reset. Personnel in danger !" es_ES="Tiempo de espera de la alarma de personal ha finalizado sin reseteo. ¡Personal en peligro!"/>
   <CSText en_US="Personal alarm" es_ES="Alarma personal"/>
   <LocalText en_US="Pers. alarm" es_ES="Alarma personal"/>
</Rsc>
```

**Explanation**: [**Muenchian grouping**](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) with key that is defined as a substring of the `id` attribute.

**II. XSLT 2.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vNewNames" select=
 "'Documentation', 'CSText', 'LocalText'"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <xsl:for-each-group select="section"
          group-by="substring-after(@id, '_42_')">

        <xsl:variable name="vId" select=
            "substring-after(@id, '42_')"/>

        <Rsc Id="{$vId}">
         <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()/*"
              group-by="@id">
           <xsl:element name=
             "{$vNewNames[starts-with(lower-case(.),current()/@id)]}">
            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
             <xsl:attribute name="{@xml:lang}" select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each>
           </xsl:element>
         </xsl:for-each-group>
        </Rsc>
     </xsl:for-each-group>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**This code uses some very powerful and most natural XSLT 2.0 features**, such as `<xsl:for-eac-group>`, `current-group()`, sequences, the `select` attribute of `<xsl:attribute>`. The result is almost twice shorter code that is much more readable and maintainable.

Comment: I'm a little surprised that you should offer an XSLT 1.0 solution to a grouping problem when the poster didn't say they were constrained to use XSLT 1.0. The solution in 2.0 would be so much easier to understand, especially for someone who is new to the language.

Comment: @Michael-Kay: I understand your feelings -- I felt the same two years ago. We have to accept the reality that people do not know and do not use XSLT 2.0. This affects the rate with which newcomers can be exposed and learn XSLT 2.0, because there are a very few people, who can guide them through XSLT 2.0 and there is a general perception of XSLT 2.0 as something "more complex". I agree that this is unfortunate, but XSLT 1.0 is what 99% (see the number of questions for XSLT, XPath, XSLT-2.0, XPath-2.0) of these people want and are asking for help with :(. Any suggestions how to improve this?

Comment: @Michael-Kay: Added an XSLT 2.0 solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a considerable amount about XSLT, but it seems like you should be able to use the XSLT [substring function](http://www.w3schools.com/Xpath/xpath_functions.asp#string) to strip out the first 22 characters of each section[id] and return the significant portion.

Comment: Thanks, Jeremiah. I hadn't thought of using an enumeration to filter out the characters that I don't need. Kind regards, A

Answer (score 0):

Define "almost". Only then you'll be able to come up with a reasonable solution. Most likely you will then solve it yourself with basic xslt functions.

Comment: ouch, okay. Forgot to mention what I thought was obvious...that I'm a newbie and struggling.